# positioning hr in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an `<hr>` that needs to be 80% width of its parent and "left justified", not centered as default.

```
<div>
    <p>Some stupid text</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Ask a stupid text, what?</p>
</div>
```

I solved this in modern browsers by using:

```
hr
{
    width: 80%;
    color: #90b124;
    background: #90b124;
    height: 4px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
```

But in IE (all versions) it's still centered. The design calls for this left positioned hr. Of course I could just use a `<span>` and call it a day but that's less semantic.

Is there a way to position this as deisred in IE?

http://jsfiddle.net/jWcEp/

Comment: Not in front of IE right now, but what happens if you add float:left; to the hr{}?

Comment: It floats left. I just add `clear: both;` to the other elements and all's well. Good solution, write it up as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know @Nicsoft's answer worked for you, but there's yet another way.

`<hr>` used to have an `align` attribute, which is not supported in HTML5. This has been replaced with CSS property `text-align` for IE and Opera and `margin-left/right` for Firefox and WebKit. So to left align you can do:

```
hr {
    margin-left:0
    text-align:left;
    width:80%;
}
```

As seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_align_css) and described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hr_align.asp).

Comment: Yes, that's a very good way to do it. And it also avoids floating, which I like to do whenever possible.

Comment: I agree with this one as the best answer, avoiding floating is good if floating is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add float:left to the hr{}

```
hr
{
    float:left; //Makes the element float to he left
    width: 80%;
    color: #90b124;
    background: #90b124;
    height: 4px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to clear as appropriate as well.